# About Code First Database Evolution (aka Migrations)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I watched a screencast from MSDN [BLOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx) that talks about database migration.

Is there anyone who knows when can we use this feature? It looks it doesn't work in CTP5 yet.

By the way, is there any way to seed the initial data after I changed the schema code?

This is what am I doing right now, it wipes all the data every time I altered the model.

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<Context>(
    new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
```

Comment: i'll vote you up just for you not to have '666' as your reputation anymore.... that can't be good ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They most likely get this migration feature in the RTM version which is targeted for the first quarter of 2011.

To populate database with some initial data you can create your own database initializer and have it inherit from your desired strategy (right now we have 2 options) and then override *Seed* method inside it:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(InheritanceMappingContext context)
    {        
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity()
        {
            ...
        };
        context.MyEntities.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Morteza, what assembly is the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in?  I am trying to follow the ASP.Net tutorial on creating the Music Store and they're using the same call and I get an exception:

Comment: I'm guessing the migration feature hasn't been added to EF as of this writing?

Comment: No, it has been cut off from the 4.1 RTW and is targeted for the next EF release. The team is actively working on this feature and showed a preview of it in the TechEd 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha 3 is out now.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

EF 4.1 Candidate Release has been issued in March and looks like this Migration feature is not yet included